# Copy files to different locations depending on information from XML file

Tags: xml, powershell

I do have the following XML file and the files `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt`, `file4.txt`, `file5.txt`...

```xml
<Oses>
    <OS>
        <Name>Windows 7</Name>
        <Version>6.1</Version>
        <File>file1.txt</File>
        <File>file2.txt</File>
    </OS>
    <OS>
        <Name>Windows Server 2012</Name>
        <Version>6.2</Version>
        <File>file3.txt</File>
        <File>file2.txt</File>
    </OS>
    <OS>
        <Name>Windows Server 2012R2</Name>
        <Version>6.3</Version>
        <File>file4.txt</File>
    </OS>
    <OS>
        <Name>Windows 10</Name>
        <Version>10.0</Version>
        <File>file5.txt</File>
        <File>file6.txt</File>
        <File>file4.txt</File>
    </OS>
</Oses>
```

Im able to read the document with PowerShell like so:

```psh
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\Desktop\New folder\test.xml'
```

Now the question is, how can I copy those files to a new folder in within `C:\` depending on the OS? Each of those files in a different location with a different name depending on the operating system?

Updated:

I had added to the beginning of the Script

New-Item -Type Directory "c:\Windows 7";

New-Item -Type Directory "c:\Windows Server 2012";

The files do copy onto the correspondent folders however , how could I create those folders using the field "Version" within the xml. Using its value as a name for the folders itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to define a hashtable that maps operating systems to destination folders:

```
$dst = @{
  'Windows 7'             = 'C:\some\where\win7'
  'Windows Server 2012'   = 'C:\some\where\win2012'
  'Windows Server 2012R2' = 'C:\some\where\win2012r2'
  'Windows 10'            = 'C:\some\where\win10'
}
```

Then you can process the XML data like this:

```
$XmlDocument.Oses.OS | ForEach-Object {
  $os = $_.Name
  $_.File | Copy-Item -Destination $dst[$os]
}
```

Comment: How could I create this directory "C:\some\where\win7" if it doesnt exist? I had tried adding -Force but doesnt seem to work..

Comment: @AutDev When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849795.aspx). Folders can be created via `New-Item -Type Directory`.